# How to use tensorflow_federated in Google Colab?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I tried everything, even the below commands, but nothing is working!

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.14
!pip install tensorflow-federated==0.4.0
# The latest version of tensorflow-federated is not working with the colab python version.
!pip install --quiet --upgrade nest-asyncio
```

Can somebody explain it or give the steps from the beginning on how to use tensorflow-federated without any errors on Google Colab only?

Comment: Try downloading the latest stable versions

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to install `Tensorflow 1.x` in Google Colab as it's been deprecated to use in Colab and also the python version upgraded to 3.10 in Colab which will only support the latest `Tensorflow 2.x` version (TF 2.8 to 2.12).

Tensorflow package is pre-installed in Google colab and you can import the latest stable tensorflow version in colab as below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
```

Output: `'2.12.0'`

Please use below command to install and import the **TF Federated** module and restart the kernel. This will install the latest TF Federated version (0.60.0) in Google Colab.

```
pip install tensorflow-federated

import tensorflow_federated as tff
print(tff.__version__)
print(tff.federated_computation(lambda: 'Hello, World!')())
```

Output:

```
0.60.0
b'Hello, World!'
```